# Flask not picking up URL argument from AJAX call

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm submitting a string and want to retrieve it back from the server. The issue seems to be that Flask's Request module isn't picking up the URL arguments - i.e. I get "HELLO" instead of the string variable.

As an aside, console.log(status) is undefined, and I'm not sure if that's related.

Here is the HTML...

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<form>
    <input id = "entered_string" name = "string">
    <input type = "button" value = "submit" id = "submit_button">
</form>

<div id = "result">?</div>

<script>
$("#submit_button").bind("click", function(data, status){
    var string = $("#entered_string").val()
    console.log(string)
    console.log(data)
    console.log(status)
    $.get('/upper_case', function(string){
        console.log(string)
        $("#result").text(string.result)
        })
    })
</script>
</html>
```

and the server code...

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def case_converter():
    return render_template("new.html")

@app.route('/upper_case')
def upper():
    print request.args
    string = request.args.get('string', "hello", type=str)
    print string
    return jsonify(result = string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you expect, that the callback of `bind` gets as arguments? There is only a single one `event`.

You have to send the string to the server:

```
$.get('/upper_case', {string:string}, function(string){
    console.log(string)
    $("#result").text(string.result)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure why I missed this :-/